# Using events non-interactively in bash

Tags: bash

In Bash, I want to get the arguments I used last time I used the command `foo`. Interactively, I can use an event designator by  by typing `!foo:*`. Is there any way to use events non-interactively, e.g., within a function? I managed to get a similar effect this way, but it seems extremely hacky:

```
$(fc -s foo=echo foo 2> /dev/null)
```

P.S. Anyone have any suggestions for more appropriate tags for this question? Are there any tags that have to do with the `!` event designator in Bash, or anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bash `history` builtin's `-p` option:

> `-p` perform history expansion on each ARG and display the result without storing it in the history list

eg: `fooargs=$(history -p '!foo:*')`

The quote above is from `help history`